# Calculate production schedule in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am reproducing a production schedule originally in Excel and need some help calculating the production quantity in R.

End goal is to build the monthly demand in the fewest count of days.

The logic in Excel determines if the day is a build day by calculating the modulo of the production day of month and production interval, then looks at the cumulative quantity built to date and if the remaining demand is greater than the max production quantity then the max production quantity is scheduled, otherwise the remaining demand quantity is scheduled.

One complication is that the first production order should be scheduled on the first production day of the month and all the other build days are offset by one to account for this first day of production.

If demand for the month is less than the max order quantity, I would want to schedule the entire month's demand on that first day but not the max order quantity.

Below is an example of the desired outcome in the highlighted column:

[image]

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please share some data in a copy/pasteable R format. `dput()` can help. Images of data are painful to import.

Comment: Sorry about the image, I was a bit too rushed when posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
It's clunky but I figured it out...

One key insight to a non-mathematician like me was that 1 %% anything returns 1.  That allowed me to write the following chunk that got the placement of quantities on the right days.

```
production_revisions <- production_revisions %>%
  arrange(SKU, date) %>%
  mutate(revised_production_quantity = ifelse(production_day_of_month %% production_interval == 1, 
                                        ifelse(revised_quantity < max_order_quantity, 
                                          revised_quantity, 
                                          max_order_quantity),
                                        0))
```

But it left an extra day of production towards the end of the month usually so I then calculated the cumulative production quantity built to date that month

```
production_revisions <- production_revisions %>% group_by(SKU, year, month) %>% arrange(SKU, date) %>% mutate(cumulative_production_quantity = cumsum(revised_production_quantity))
```

...and then used this piece to get rid of that last build if we had already built enough to meet demand.  I also adjusted it to build just what was needed to meet demand if the remainng quantity to be built was less than the max order quantity

```
production_revisions <- production_revisions %>% mutate(revised_production_quantity = ifelse(cumulative_production_quantity > revised_quantity,
                                                                                        ifelse(revised_quantity - lag(cumulative_production_quantity, 1) > 0,
                                                                                          revised_quantity - lag(cumulative_production_quantity, 1),
                                                                                          0),
                                                                                        revised_production_quantity))
```

...and finally, recalculated the cumulative production quantity to ensure that production perfectly matches demand (in a perfect world).

```
production_revisions <- production_revisions %>% group_by(SKU, year, month) %>% arrange(SKU, date) %>% mutate(cumulative_production_quantity = cumsum(revised_production_quantity))
```